# HandlebarsJS: matching pre-compile/runtime versions, still 'Uncaught TypeError'

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, typeerror

Handlebars compile version: 4.0.8
Handlebars runtime version: 4.0.8

main.js example:

```
var tiles = {
"friends": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lolita Simmons"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Matthews Hunter"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pace Slater"
  }
]};

var template = Handlebars.templates['search-card.tmpl'];
            $("#print-search-card").html(template(tiles));
```

I'm running into an issue that seems to plague handlebars:

`Uncaught TypeError: template is not a function`

I've made sure that my versions are matching, dependencies are updated, and that my js files are served in the correct order.

I've checked compiling revisions with `Handlebars.COMPILER_REVISION` and they match the compile values for my templates (7).

How I precompile (with NPM Handlebars):

1. Move to folder where un-compiled template file lives (search-card).
2. In console: 'Handlebars search-card -f search-card.tmpl'

Comment: How are you including search-card.tmpl?

Comment: Files are in the footer in this order, top to bottom: jquery->Handlebars->search-card.tmpl->main.js

Comment: show how are you including them please. Paste code.

Comment: `<!-- lib -->
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>
    <!-- templates -->
    <script src="js/templates/search-card.tmpl"></script>
    <!-- json -->
    <script src="js/json/data.js"></script>
    <!-- main js -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>`

Comment: Here's the ID in the html that the template is attached to: '<div id="print-search-card"></div>'

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When precompiling handlebars using:

```
handlebars ${input-file} -f ${output-file}
```

The template name is taken from the input file.

So when doing:

```
handlebars search-card -f search-card.tmpl
```

the template name will be `search-card` and not `search-card.tmpl`

Change your code to:

```
var template = Handlebars.templates['search-card']; //Without the extension
```

### Tests:

To prove this, I created a template called: `search-card` with the following content:

```
<div class="">{{name}}</div>
```

Then I compiled using:

```
handlebars search-card -f foo.tmpl
```

**Output:**

```
    (function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['search-card'] = template({"compiler":[7,">= 4.0.0"],"main":function(container,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var helper;

  return "<div>"
    + container.escapeExpression(((helper = (helper = helpers.name || (depth0 != null ? depth0.name : depth0)) != null ? helper : helpers.helperMissing),(typeof helper === "function" ? helper.call(depth0 != null ? depth0 : (container.nullContext || {}),{"name":"name","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
    + "</div>\n";
},"useData":true});
})();
```

Notice the `templates['search-card']` part of the output.

In case your input file has an extension, the template **will have** that extension. The only exception is `.handlebars` extension that will be stripped:

> The compiler will insert templates in Handlebars.templates. If your
>   input file is person.handlebars, the compiler will insert it at
>   Handlebars.templates.person. This template will be a function that may
>   be directly executed in the same manner as templates compiled locally.

**search-card.hbs**

```
Handlebars.templates['search-card.hbs']
```

**search-card.handlebars**

```
Handlebars.templates['search-card']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, han sido de gran ayuda.